# Network latency monitoring script windows

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, vbscript

I'm trying to write script which will run ping command and from output it will get average latency and % of packet loss values, i tried with below command which works well

```
`ping -n 8 4.4.4.4  > D:\latency.txt

C:\Users\tnt5273>ping 4.2.2.2

Pinging 4.2.2.2 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 4.2.2.2: bytes=32 time=253ms TTL=54
Reply from 4.2.2.2: bytes=32 time=242ms TTL=54
Reply from 4.2.2.2: bytes=32 time=252ms TTL=54
Reply from 4.2.2.2: bytes=32 time=248ms TTL=54
Reply from 4.2.2.2: bytes=32 time=253ms TTL=54
Reply from 4.2.2.2: bytes=32 time=242ms TTL=54
Reply from 4.2.2.2: bytes=32 time=252ms TTL=54
Reply from 4.2.2.2: bytes=32 time=248ms TTL=54

Ping statistics for 4.2.2.2:
    Packets: Sent = 8, Received = 8, Lost = 0 (**0% loss**),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 242ms, Maximum = 253ms, Average = **248ms** `
```

However challenge here is i want to somehow grab just numerical vales from output(so threshold can be set) and publish them in plain text file as
Loss value in% Average value in ms 
0 248

, I'm not sure how to do it in windows, looking for help in VB or windows shell scripting  which can help me to achieve my objective

TIA

Comment: If you parse it be aware that the output may be different depending on the locale. I would use the powershell object like Paul answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem Initialize variables to hold data
    set "pct="
    set "avg="

    rem Run the ping and filter to only read the required lines
    rem The first line will contain the loss percentage
    rem The second line will contain the average roundtrip
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('
        ping -n 8 4.4.4.4 ^| findstr /r /c:"= [0-9]*ms" /c:"([0-9]*%% "
    ') do if not defined pct (

        rem Extract the % loss from the line
        for /f "tokens=2 delims=(%%" %%b in ("%%a") do set "pct=%%b"

    ) else (

        rem Retrieve the last element in the line (the average)
        for %%b in (%%a) do set "avg=%%b"
    )

    rem Remove the ms literal from the average    
    for /f "delims=m" %%a in ("%avg%") do set "avg=%%a"

    rem Echo the retrieved values
    echo pct=[%pct%] 
    echo avg=[%avg%]
```

Maybe a little more code than expected, but in my system (spanish locale) the loss percentage is shown in a separate line and the literals are not the same.

Comment: Thanks you are invited for party :)

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest to use Test-Connection instead of ping.exe since it returns an object from which you can get the data you need easily.

Example:

```
$count= 8
$con = Test-Connection 4.2.2.2 -count $count
$average = ($con.ResponseTime | Measure-Object -Average).Average
$lost = $count-($con.count)
```

Comment: how do i use test-connection ?

Comment: @tnt5273 i was on mobile, i have added an example now

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=3 delims=," %%# in ('ping -n 8 173.194.44.131 2^>nul^| findstr /i "loss average"') do (
    set "%%#"
)


for /f "tokens=1 delims= " %%a in ("%Average %") do echo average-%%a
for /f "tokens=2 delims=() " %%a in ("%Lost %") do echo loss-%%a
```

On the last two lines you can change the output - the `%%a` is the value loss and average are the clarification strings.And you can output the result to a file.

Comment: Thanks you are invited for party :)